# Google Cloud PHP mail function is not working and cannot add another email as authorized senders

Tags: php, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Cloud. I have recently installed a LAMP-Debian 8 instance. Everything works well, but the PHP mail function is not working. I have followed like Google Cloud documentation, but it's still not working.

Here is what I did so far:

1. Installed LAMP-Debian on Google Cloud
2. An external domain pointed as this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart) (*NewDomain.com*)
3. Ran a test mail with simple PHP mail function but it's not working.
4. As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/#sending_mail) I set *Email API authorized senders*
   under *App Engine* -> *Settings*

   - Here I can only add my Google email (*MyUsername@MyDomain.com*) as *Email API authorized senders*.
   - but I cannot add any other emails that related with pointed domain (*info@NewDomain.com*)
   - Also I cannot add this format emails that Google suggests  (*anything@[APP_ALIAS].appspotmail.com*)
5. Again I did a test with mailing code, but it's still not working.

   > ```
   > <?php
   > //located: var/www/html/testmail.php
   > $to = "myOtherEmail@OtherDomain.com";
   > $subject = "My subject";
   > $txt = "Hello world!";
   > $headers = 'From: MyUsername@MyDomain.com';
   > mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
   > ?>
   > ```

Comment: Why don't you try sendgrid or mailjet?

Comment: @AvinashRaj actually I have to work with WordPress and ContactForm7 so I think php mail() is better.